# C# Web API Parameter Always Returns All Values Instead of One

Tags: c#, json, sql-server, asp.net-web-api, parameters

I am working on a Web API in C# and am getting my data from a SQL Database. The Get method returns all rows of (student) data, however even when I put a single student number in the GET call, it still returns all rows of data instead of a single row for the specified student. In my Roles Class I have;

```
public class Roles
    {

        List<Roles> studentRoles = new List<Roles>();
        
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string PersonName { get; set; }
        public string Profile { get; set; }
        public string Level { get; set; }
        public int Year { get; set; }
        public string Department { get; set; }
    }

    public class readRoles : Roles
    {
        public readRoles(DataRow dataRow)
        {
            UserName = (string)dataRow["UserName"];
            PersonName = (string)dataRow["PersonName"];
            Profile = (string)dataRow["Profile"];
            Level = (string)dataRow["Level"];
            Year = Convert.ToInt32(dataRow["Year"]);
            Department = (dataRow["Department"] == DBNull.Value) ? "No Department" : dataRow["Department"].ToString();
        }

        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string PersonName { get; set; }
        public string Profile { get; set; }
        public string Level { get; set; }
        public int Year { get; set; }
        public string Department { get; set; }
    }
```

In my Controller I have this;

```
    List<Roles> studentRoles = new List<Roles>();

        private SqlDataAdapter _adapter;
        public IEnumerable<Roles> Get()
        {
            //Create link to database
            string connString;
            SqlConnection con;
            connString = @"XXX";
            DataTable _dt = new DataTable();
            con = new SqlConnection(connString);
            con.Open();

            var sql = "some sql here";


            SqlCommand CMD = new SqlCommand();
            CMD.Connection = con;
            CMD.CommandText = sql;
            CMD.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
            SqlDataReader dr = CMD.ExecuteReader();
            _adapter = new SqlDataAdapter
            {
                SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(sql, con)
            };
            _adapter.Fill(_dt);
            List<Roles> roles = new List<Roles>(_dt.Rows.Count);
            if (_dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (DataRow studentrole in _dt.Rows)
                {
                    roles.Add(new readRoles(studentrole));
                }
            }

            return roles;

        }
```

The above returns all the data as it should. To return a single row of data, I have the below Method but it still returns every single row instead of the row for the specified one when I do e.g. https://localhost:XXXXX/custom-roles-api/campusCustomRoles/12345;

```
        [HttpGet] 
        public IHttpActionResult Get(string userName)
        {

            string connString;
            SqlConnection con;
            connString = @"XXX";
            DataTable _dt = new DataTable();
            con = new SqlConnection(connString);
            con.Open();
 
            var sql = "select distinct .... where student_reference = " + userName +;


            SqlCommand CMD = new SqlCommand();
            CMD.Connection = con;
            CMD.CommandText = sql;
            CMD.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
            SqlDataReader dr = CMD.ExecuteReader();
            _adapter = new SqlDataAdapter
            {
                SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(sql, con)
            };
            _adapter.Fill(_dt);
            List<Roles> roles = new List<Roles>(_dt.Rows.Count);
            if (_dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (DataRow studentrole in _dt.Rows)
                {
                    roles.Add(new readRoles(studentrole));
                }
            }

            var singlestu =  roles.FirstOrDefault(e => e.UserName == userName);
            return Ok(singlestu)
            ;
        }
```

In the above example, I expect only data for student 12345 to be returned, but alas, all records are retrieved. In my WebConfig file, I have a custom Route like so;

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API routes


            // This is the original Route
            //config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            //config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            //    name: "DefaultApi",
            //    routeTemplate: "api/{Controller}/{id}",
            //    //routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            //    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            //);


            // Custom Route  
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            // Define route
            System.Web.Http.Routing.IHttpRoute rolesRoute = config.Routes.CreateRoute("custom-roles-api/{controller}/{id}",
                                                    new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }, null);
            // Add route
            config.Routes.Add("DefaultApi", rolesRoute);

        }
```

Not sure where I have gone wrong and would be grateful for any pointers.

Many thanks in advance.

EDIT: As requested, please see below code when I used parameters;

```
 [HttpGet] 
        public IHttpActionResult Get(string userName)
        {

            string connString;
            SqlConnection con;
            connString = @"XXXX";
            DataTable _dt = new DataTable();
            con = new SqlConnection(connString);
            con.Open();
 
            var sql = "select distinct .... where student_reference =@UserName " +
                      "and department ='LAW' " +;


            SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter();
            param.ParameterName = "@UserName";
            param.Value = UserName;
            
            SqlCommand CMD = new SqlCommand();
            CMD.Connection = con;
            CMD.CommandText = sql;
            CMD.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
            SqlDataReader dr = CMD.ExecuteReader();
            _adapter = new SqlDataAdapter
            {
                SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(sql, con)
            };
            _adapter.Fill(_dt);
            List<Roles> roles = new List<Roles>(_dt.Rows.Count);
            if (_dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (DataRow studentrole in _dt.Rows)
                {
                    roles.Add(new readRoles(studentrole));
                }
            }

            var singlestu =  roles.FirstOrDefault(e => e.UserName == userName);
            return Ok(singlestu)
            ;
        }
```

Comment: `"...where student = " + userName +;`  isn't parameterisation, it's **injection**; a severe and fatal security vulnerability for you and your users. [Why do we always prefer using parameters in SQL statements?](//stackoverflow.com/q/7505808)

Comment: @Larnu thank you for your response and for the warning. But, do you have any suggestions in relation to how I can retrieve just the one student? Many thanks.

Comment: When you parametrise the statement, do you have the same problem?

Comment: @Larnu Yes I still have the same problem...

Comment: Please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75471343/edit) your question to show how you've updated the code to use parameters, it seems there's still something wrong.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I have now edited the question to show how I used parameters...

Answer (score 0):

After much head-cracking, I go it to work by converting the UserName to type int in the Roles class and the source query.